# c++ переопределение оператора для разных типов

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить следующую ситуацию:

Есть класс `CFraction` у которого есть в том числе конструктор `CFraction(int)`.

Сложение переопределил следующим образом:

```
CFraction operator + (const CFraction<T>& value) const;
```

Но хотелось бы, чтобы можно было выполнять и операции с `int`, например

```
CFraction val2 = val1 + 11;
```

Добавление такого оператора не помогает :(

```
CFraction operator + (const int value) const;
```

Подскажите PLZ как решить корректно данную задачу?

И как я понимаю корректно сделать `11 + val1` не получится, потому что сначала конвертация в `int` будет?

Comment: Гм.. https://ideone.com/SaIMDt - что тут не так?... А `11+val1` - нужен просто свободный оператор, а не член класса, только и всего.

Comment: Harry, супер, посмотрев на код я увидел  у себя ошибку - у меня просто тоже шаблон и для `CFraction operator + (const int value) const;` у меня указывался шаблон, а его надо было бы убрать. Убрал и заработало. А касательно свободного оператора не очень понял - что именно надо сделать?

Comment: Написать вне класса оператор `CFraction operator+(int,const CFraction&)`

Comment: @Harry, а такой концептуальный вопрос - нужно ли тогда тот же оператор для нескольких типов переопределять или можно обойтись несколькими универсальными перегрузками? Например если мне сложение надо определить для скажем `CFraction`, `CData`, `int`, `double` - мне надо 4 оператора (ну или 8 чтобы с 2 концов работало) переопределять?

Comment: "Серебряной пули не существует" (с)

Comment: @Harry, а не подскажешь PLZ ещё как переопределить оператор сложения, чтобы он реагировал на конструкции `{x,y}`. Когда я создал конструктор `CFraction(const int, const int)`, то появилась возможность инициализировать переменные так: `CFraction num = {1, 2};`, а как должен выглядеть оператор `+`, чтобы можно было делать так `num2 = num1 + {1, 2};`?